# Preventing reloading of reported comments

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to prevent comments that have been reported from being reloaded in my commentsTable. So I made a removedIDs table:

```
 var removedIDs = [Comment]()
```

I also have

```
 var comments = [Comment] ()
```

Then I wanted to have that when you report a comment, it adds it to the list so:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? { let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Report") { action, index in self.comments.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) }; more.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue; self.removedIDs.append(comments[indexPath.row]); return [more]           
}
```

Then I thought when loading comments I could have:

```
func loadComments(forPostId: String) {
    let ref = self.ref.child("comments")
    let thisPostRef = ref.child(forPostId)
    thisPostRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let allComments = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for commentSnap in allComments {
            let commenterUid = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "comment_by_uid").value as? String ?? "No uid"
            let commentText = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "comment_text").value as? String ?? "No comment"
          let aComment = Comment(id: commenterUid, text: commentText)
            if removedIDs.contains(aComment){
                print("skipped")
            }
            else {
                self.comments.append(aComment)
                print(commenterUid, commentText)
            }
        }
        self.commentsTable.reloadData()
    })
}
```

But I get the error

> Argument type 'Comment' does not conform to expected type 'Equatable'

on the line: removedIDs.contain(aComment){

Note that my comment model is as follows:

```
import Foundation
```

class Comment{

```
var id:String
var text:String
init(id: String, text:String) {
    self.id = id
    self.text = text


}
static func parseComment(_ key:String, data:[String:Any]) -> Comment? {
    if let text = data["text"] as? String{
        return Comment(id: key, text: text)
    }


    return nil
    }
}
```

How can I implement this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `removedIDs.contain(aComment){`   needs `Equatable` conformance

```
  class Comment : Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Comment, rhs: Comment) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    var id:Int!
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where I would put this code. It would make sense to add it to my class Comment model (which I have now added to the post for your reference) but the id should be a string for this model.

Comment: Also, the id is a string in my model. Can I replace it with an int?

Comment: Now, when I delete one comment, it adds them all to my removedIDs. So I get "skipped skipped skipped" in my console for three comments when I only want to get 1 comment skipped for one deletion, the comment I deleted. How can I make sure it only skips the comment I clicked report on?

Comment: In fact, even if I add a new comment, that will be skipped as well.

Comment: Could I maybe do it with a function like "mutating func subtract(_ other: IndexSet)" and then do "comments.subtract(removedIDs)"? I am currently having trouble decalring this function though